# SQL error in PHP with " and '?

Tags: php, html, sql, syntax-error

When I run the my php coding, 
Input from page addresident1.php, post data to addresident2.php to process, it show:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '","' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in F:\xampp\htdocs\1\1\addresident2.php on line 5

This is my coding on line 5, in page addresident2.php:

```
$query = "insert into resident 
values("",".$_POST["txtICNo"].",'".$_POST["txtName"]."','".$_POST["txtNo"]."',
'".$_POST["txtHouse"]."','".$_POST["txtKL"]."','".$_POST["txtTelHouse"]."',
'".$_POST["txtTelMobile"]."','".$_POST["txtJantina"]."','".$_POST["txtKaum"]."',
'".$_POST["txtJenisPenghuni"]."')";
```

"" in some part above means insert Null value.

I am wondering am I wrong with symbol " or '.
Please check for me. Thanks.

Comment: Use single quotes(`'`) to quote your string values.

Comment: I should note that your code and many of these answers are vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: @Musa
I should use single quotes inside the bracket? or, to quote ".$_POST["txtName"]."  ?

Comment: @icktoofay thank you for reminding. But I cannot find solution there because my coding involved in PHP POST method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this `.$_POST["txtICNo"]` have no single quotes like others. and your post values :

`$_POST["txtKL"]` should use single quotes too: `$_POST['txtKL']`, I recommend you to do it like this:

```
  $null = "";
  $txtICNo = $_POST['txtICNo'];
  $txtName = $_POST['txtName'];
   ...//and so on
 $query = "insert into resident values('$null','$txtICNo', '$txtName', ..and so on..)";
```

good luck !!

Comment: This is the type of the attribute under Resident.

1. NULL              int(6)
2. txtICNo           bigint(12)
3. txtName           varchar(30)
4. txtNo             int(2)
5. txtHouse          int(6)
6. txtKL             varchar(6)
7. txtTelHouse       varchar(10)
8. txtTelMobile      varchar(11)
9. txtJantina        varchar(10）
10.txtKaum           varchar(20)
11.txtJenisPenghuni  varchar(20)

Comment: May I know, why txtKL should use single code in the bracket?

Comment: do you mean single quotes?

Comment: look? http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Yes. Sorry. Typo error. It's single quotes.

Comment: Your recommendation work! You made me understand the coding. Thank you.

Comment: congrats !! glad can help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to build a string for the query, which you aren't doing. You have a string of

> "insert into resident values("

Then no concatenation symbol, and then the start of another string. PHP doesn't understand what you are doing. I think you are trying to do something like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `RESIDENT` VALUES('$val1', '$val2')";
```

You should also not be pulling directly from the $_POST data, as it is unsanitary. Take a look at the PHP `mysqli` prepared statement library: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php
$query = "INSERT  INTO resident 
values('','".$_POST['txtICNo']."','".$_POST['txtName']."','".$_POST['txtNo']."',
'".$_POST['txtHouse']."','".$_POST['txtKL']."','".$_POST['txtTelHouse']."',
'".$_POST['txtTelMobile']."','".$_POST['txtJantina']."','".$_POST['txtKaum']."',
'".$_POST['txtJenisPenghuni']."')";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your first value that you are setting to null to either single quotes - `'`, or escaped double quotes - `\"`

```
values('', ...
```

or

```
values(\"\", ...
```